# How do I count up in Firebase Firestore in front-end

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am creating an app that allows users to track new habits, using Firestore to save the users' data. 
The data stored in the database are the following:

- Title (name of the habit)
- Count (how many times have I done the habit)
- Goal (how many times do I want to check this habit daily/weekly/monthly)
- Streak (how many days/weeks/month/ in a row have I checked this habit)

My goal is to essentially click on an object (in this case the flame in the `#container`), and for the *count* to add up in the database.

This is what I have got right now:

```
// Real-time listener
db.collection('habits').onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
    snapshot.docChanges().forEach(change => {
        if(change.type === 'added'){
            renderHabit(change.doc.data(), change.doc.id);
        }
    });
})

// Add new habit
const form = document.querySelector('form');
form.addEventListener('submit', evt => {
    evt.preventDefault();
    const habit = {
        title: form.habitTitle.value,
        count: 0,
        goal: form.habitGoal.value,
        streak: 0
    };

    db.collection('habits').add(habit)
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
    form.habitTitle.value = '';
    form.habitGoal.value = '';
})

// Update counter
const habitContainer = document.querySelector('.newHabit');
habitContainer.addEventListener('click', evt => {
    //console.log(evt);
    if(evt.target.tagName === 'I'){
        const id = evt.target.getAttribute('data-id');
        db.collection('habits').doc(id).update({
            count: 1
        });
    }
});

const habits = document.querySelector('.newHabit');

// Render habit data
const renderHabit = (data, id) => {
    const html = `
        <div id="wrapper" data-id="${id}">
            <div id="container">
                <span id="title">${data.title}</span>
                <div class="streakContainer">
                    <span id="streak">${data.streak}</span>
                    <i data-id="${id}"></i>
                </div>

                <div class="countContainer">
                    <span id="count">${data.count}</span>
                    <span>/</span>
                    <span id="goal">${data.goal}</span>
                </div>

                <div id="progressbar">
                    <div id="timer"></div>
                    <div id="progressbaroverlay"></div> 
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    `;

    habits.innerHTML += html;
};
```

I have tried to declare `var countNumber = 0;` to eventually use `countNumber = countNumber++` on the clickevent inside `// Update counter`, this doesn't work because countNumber gets set to 0 again on refresh (I believe).

Hopefully I'm clear enough :)

Thanks!

Comment: Where is `countNumber` in your code? Are you using a state container of any kind on the front end?

Comment: @jmargolisvt I have deleted `countNumber` from my code since it didn't work, but I had it declared at the top of my JS file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to increment a number in the database is with the `increment` operator:

```
habitContainer.addEventListener('click', evt => {
    if(evt.target.tagName === 'I'){
        const id = evt.target.getAttribute('data-id');
        db.collection('habits').doc(id).update({
            count: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1)
        });
    }
});
```

Every time you call this, your `onSnapshot` listener will be called again with the updated document. You'll want to handle `if(change.type === 'modified'){` in there to show the updated value/document in the UI.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks. I can't figure out what to put in the `if(change.type === 'changed'){}` to update the UI as well.. oh and btw, isn't `'changed'` supposed to be `'modified'`?

Comment: Oops. That could well be. :)

Comment: Hi Frank, I've been struggling to update the UI for some time now and I can't seem to figure it out. I've come to this thus far: `if(change.type === 'modified'){
            const habitUpdate = document.querySelector('#wrapper[data-id="' + change.doc.id + '"]');
            // li.childNodes[0].textContent = change.doc.data().count;
            habitUpdate.update();
        }` Any tips on how to improve this so the UI gets updated aswell?

Comment: At first glance that looks good. Are you updating the `innerHTML` of the element too? If you can't figure it out, it might be worth posting a new question with only the update part of it (so see if you can get the same problem without using Firestore).

Comment: Finally got it to work. All I had to do was change the `.querySelector` to the `id` where the updated value was in the first place, and therefore remove `.childNodes[]`. Thanks anyway for your help!